# Private Domain Email Flagged as Spam After Switching From HTTP to SSL

Tags: email, ssl, outlook, gmail, spam

I have just started building a site which sends me mail from a contact form using a single private domain email address. When my site was http, all emails were going straight into Outlook and Gmail inboxes. I was debugging ajax POST therefore sending myself a flurry of emails which suddenly stopped, before I realised they got junked from the moment I switched on SSL.

Is there a good reason for this?

*N.B. This isn't a question about configuring DKIM or general domain/IP trust, but specifically why email sent from a domain with SSL vs same domain on http might be deemed less trustworthy as the former.*

Comment: If your website is using HTTP or HTTPS has nothing to do with the way how emails are sent at all - unless you are doing some strange things on how you send mail.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich That's exactly what I thought and yet, if I disable HTTPS emails go to inbox, switch back on HTTPS emails go to spam. I'm using a very simple SMTP config with Pear Mail to send plain text mail.

Comment: Did you look at the raw MIME email source in your Gmail mailbox?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Thanks for nudging me in the right direction. The junked emails were failing SPF auth - it was a DNS config error on my part. I was switching between backups of a config with SSL and non SSL to test and the SPF TXT record was only in the non-SSL config ‍♂️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging through example MIME sources I tracked the problem down to SPF auth timeouts. When testing I was switching between DNS record backups, one SSL and one non-SSL. This was caused by my non-SSL config not containing the SPF TXT record to gain authorisation for my mail forwarder. My bad.

Lesson: debug email issues with MIME source first